How do I make noise texture follow unwrapped object
I am trying to make a specialized hair for unity, the problem right now is uv and Baking it, when I unwrap the uv the noise does not follow the hair no matter what texture coordinate that I set it to.

is there any way to make it follow the hair strand.
example of how it should look when I don't UV unwrap it below.


Editing the Uv's so that the outer edges are aligned vertically (or horizontally depending on node set-up) in the UV space may get the noise texture to follow the hair shape.
In the example below, (using a similar shader node set-up to yours), we will be aligning to the Uv's outer edges vertically then rotating the UV island 90°.

After UV unwrapping the hair mesh, select one of the outer edges of the UV island, Alt+LMB, then right click anywhere in the UV editor window to open the UV context menu and choose the Align Vertically option.
Repeat for the other outer edges of the UV island.
Select the UV's and rotate 90°.
If necessary select the end vertex and move it a little downwards along the Y axis.


Note:
Another way of creating hair cards in Blender. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sEdnd67yBuw&t=1s
Also there are lots of tutorials for creating hair cards in gimp or PS.
